# Nativescript Devtool not running properly

Tags: javascript, android, android-emulator, google-chrome-devtools, nativescript

I am using Nx and Nativscript (with this package)

> https://github.com/NativeScript/nx

I setup a project, and installed android studio with SDK 32, and Emulator device (Pixel 5 API 32)

Running my project works fine using the provided comnmand :

```
> nx run nativescript-frontend:android

―――――――――――――――――――――――― 
Running NativeScript CLI within apps/nativescript-frontend
 
ns debug android --force

...
...

To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:40000

Successfully synced application org.nativescript.frontend on device emulator-5554.
```

I can see the app on the emulated device, but I tried to turn on the dev tools using the provided URL

This result in the following logs and errors,

```
main.js:1 Main._createAppUI: 17.735107421875 ms
main.js:1 Main._showAppUI: 132.93896484375 ms
main.js:1 Main._initializeTarget: 11.730224609375 ms
main.js:1 Main._lateInitialization: 0.423828125 ms
protocol_client.js:1 Request Network.setAttachDebugStack failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Network.setAttachDebugStack' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setEmulatedMedia failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setEmulatedMedia' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setEmulatedVisionDeficiency failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setEmulatedVisionDeficiency' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Audits.enable failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Audits.enable' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request ServiceWorker.enable failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'ServiceWorker.enable' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Inspector.enable failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Inspector.enable' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Target.setAutoAttach failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Target.setAutoAttach' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Target.setDiscoverTargets failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Target.setDiscoverTargets' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Target.setRemoteLocations failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Target.setRemoteLocations' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Network.clearAcceptedEncodingsOverride failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Network.clearAcceptedEncodingsOverride' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request DOMDebugger.setBreakOnCSPViolation failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'DOMDebugger.setBreakOnCSPViolation' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Page.getNavigationHistory failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Page.getNavigationHistory' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setFocusEmulationEnabled failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setFocusEmulationEnabled' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Page.getNavigationHistory failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Page.getNavigationHistory' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
protocol_client.js:1 Request Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse' wasn't found"}
r @ protocol_client.js:1
onMessage @ protocol_client.js:1
Ur.#bo.onmessage @ sdk.js:1
```

I have no idea what I should fix to have the devtool properly working.